# Django - url is not matching any pattern when being redirected

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am working on a django project and I have a html web page and from the web page I want to pass in an Id and through that id, update a record. I have the url setup and the html page url redirect. I am passing what is needed in the url, but i am getting a pattern matching error. I tried everything and for some reason it is not working. does anyone know what is oging on or can help me figure out what is causing this error. I will attach all the info below:

Here is the url link:

```
url(r'^(?P<source_id>[\w+][0-9]+)/default_source/$', views.setDefaultSource, name='default_source'),
```

Here is the html file:

```
<p>{{account.user.username}}, {{ account.source_name }}, {{ account.source_id }},
{{ account.status }}
<a href="{% url 'default_source' account.source_id %}">Make Default</a>
```

Here is the views.py :

```
def setDefaultSource(request, source_id):
    currentUser = loggedInUser(request)
    currentSource = Dwolla.object.get(source_id = source_id)

    update_source = currentSource
    update_source.status = 2
    update_source.save()

    return redirect('home_page')
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
NoReverseMatch at /linked_accounts/
Reverse for 'default_source' with arguments '('https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/3021030d-0175-41f1-8bce-4625b8eae0fc',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<source_id>[\\w+][0-9]+)/default_source/$']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your regex expression don't match your `source_id`:

```
[\w+][0-9]+
```

[image]

if `3021030d-0175-41f1-8bce-4625b8eae0fc` is what your source_id looks like,try:

```
[\w+-]+
```

or more complex regex expression.

Comment: the source id is the following `https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/3021030d-0175-41f1-8bce-4625b8eae0fc` @zhiyucao

Answer (score 0):

Just change you url pattern to,

```
url(r'^(?P<source_id>[\w-]+)/default_source/$', views.setDefaultSource, name='default_source'),
```

Comment: So i have the following code now `url(r'^(?P<source_id>[\w+-]+)/default_source/$', views.setDefaultSource, name='default_source'),` and I am still getting the following error: `NoReverseMatch at /linked_accounts/
Reverse for 'default_source' with arguments '('https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/3021030d-0175-41f1-8bce-4625b8eae0fc',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<source_id>[\\w-]+)/default_source/$']` Not sure why @zaidfazil

Comment: Are you using any namespace for app url_patterns? Please do check in your project_level `urls.py`...

Comment: Are you sure `account.source_id` is a `uuid` , it seems that, `account.source_id` is a uri.

Comment: it is stored as a string.. i can see how to change it maybe that will help

Comment: I cchanged it to pass in a name and I got the same error. I also tried an id and it still got the same error. so does that mean the error has to do with something other than what i am passing into it @zaidfazil

Comment: I checked and it is displaying as a string type so why is this being such a pain in the butt @zaidfazil

Comment: `source_id` should only contain the `uuid`, ie, '3021030d-0‌​175-41f1-8bce-4625b8‌​eae0fc', not the complete url.

Comment: i figured it out. i just past the table record id i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... thanks for the help though @zaidfazil